# Regular expression to get cells content with link or not

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm returning the content of an HTML file which looks like this :

```
<irrelevant things> 
   <tr id="myid"> 
      <td>Content</td> 
   </tr> 
<irrelevant things again>
```

or :

```
<irrelevant things> 
   <tr id="myid"> 
      <td><a href="somewhere.com">Content</a></td> 
   </tr> 
<irrelevant things again>
```

Is it possible to get only "Content" for both cases with only one regular expression ?

I tried this but without any result :

```
preg_match('/<tr id="myid"><td>(<a href="[^\"]*">)?([^<]*)/', $html, $mycontent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how much html you are going to need to parse, but have you looked into an HTML DOM parser or something of the sort? (example: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: it's a one shot thing, I prefer handle it (if I can) in 1 or 2 lines with regular expression instead of using a library

Comment: Cool cool. Someone else may be more help than I in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with regex:

```
<td>(?:<a.*?>)?([^<]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gR1wM4)

But, it would be easier to do with DOM parsers like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Regex is not the best way for this, and since you have an id *("myid")*, you can do it easily with `DOMDocument`. Example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($yourstring);

$node = $doc->getElementById('myid');

echo trim($node->textContent);
```

Comment: @Fiti In that case, you might want to select this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Duncan: since Enissay answer do the job too (with the way choosen by the OP), and contains a mention to simple HTML DOM Parser, I don't see any reason to not accept his answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point. Also, I had misread the order of comments and thought Fiti commented on your question last (which would lead me to believe this was the preferred solution).